# how to maintain read state like gmail application in recycler view item click?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I develop one application when user click any recyclerview  view item the text color should change and its working fine, but when ever i open again my application the text color not remain change i used shared preference for saving sate but its not working any solution?
code:

```
ItemClickSupport.addTo(recyclerView).setOnItemClickListener(
        new ItemClickSupport.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v) {
                alarmDao = alarmDaos.get(position);
                alarmDao.setRead(true);
                alarmDaos.set(position, alarmDao);
                alarmAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), NotificatinActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

                try {
                    SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("isRad", alarmDao.isRead());
                    editor.putString("string", String.valueOf(alarmDao));
                    editor.apply();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This value shouldn't be stored into the SharedPreferences as it's part of the object you want to display.

As it's a DAO it means you have a database somewhere. So when the user selects the item, you update the `isRead` field and update the database.

Then when you want to display the list again, you just have to check if `isRead` is true or false to display the item's colour accordingly.

Comment: when i am in the applicatin during click on item color got change but when i am close the application and open again the color turn on is previse bold state

Comment: Yes because you need to persist the value into the database. All the rest is stored in memory and lost when the app is closed

Comment: right now am creating local getter and setter method using Boolean value but i want to change state permanently  when user read the message its always remain same.

Comment: What you're doing is changing the state in the object stored in memory. What you have to do is to update the value in the database (as I supposed you get the object from a database)

Comment: i though is sufficient to store all value in shared preference or else we have to store all change in remote  database?

Comment: Where do you get the list of `alarmDao` from?

Comment: So what you can do is to set an id (hardcoded) in your DAO object and save this id into the SharePreferences

Comment: do you have twtter id

Comment: No, why do you want a Twitter id?

Comment: i want to descripbe in detail may be you not understand properly

Comment: Then maybe you should just update your question. As you haven't approved any answers I guess nobody has really understood it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check sharedprefernce value in recyclerview adapter
and set color in bindholder .
ie ,in bindholder if clicked set selected color and not clicked set another color

sharedprefrence will not be a great solution because all position state should be saved clicked or not . if want to use sharedprefernce make it an array of states accoridng to position and save in it.

array of states is needed for every postion or use sqllite

Answer (score 0):

Use SqLite Database , Save list of items in database and include ReadUnRead column in Table. whenever user clicks item set ReadUnRead to 1 and in Recycler Adapter OnBindView any item that has ReadUnRead equal to 1 change its color.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `database` and make a one `Boolean` variable like true.false for that and set a value in this variable if it's clicked then changed it's value true. or another solution is you need to create a s`hared preference` and set and get a value from this but i recommended to you use a `database`.